# when does a positive definite quadratic form has unique maximizer over n-dimensional rectangle (hypercube)?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

problem description:
A quadratic
programming problem on n-dimensional rectangle:
$\max_{\textbf{x}}[\textbf{x}^{\top}\Sigma \textbf{x}+\alpha^{\top}\textbf{x}],s.t.: x_i\in [\underline{x}_i,\overline{x}_i],\forall i$
$\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix.

My question: under what condition, will this problem has unique solution?

Comment: For the general case of your problem, there will always be at least one rectangle vertex which is a global maximum. Here's an example which doesn't have a unique global maximizer. Let $\Sigma = $ n dimensional Identity matrix, $\alpha$ = zero vector, and rectangle limits at +/- 1 per component. Then all $2^n$ vertices are global maximizers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there some existing results about the uniqueness of solution to this problem?